# Scaling of CAT(0) metric

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Suppose $(X,d)$ is  a geodesic metric space which satisfies CAT(0) inequality.Now if we rescale the metric $d$ then will it still be a CAT(0) metric space i.e, all geodesic triangles satisfies CAT(0) inequality.? 
here Scaling means $ d'(x,y) = \lambda d(x,y)$ for some $\lambda $ positive.
I am confused as if a space is CAT(k) for some $k < 0$ then after rescaling the metric it will become CAT(-1).But i am getting stuck in this question.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Just follow the definition and the fact that the Euclidean plane (unlike hyperbolic planes) admits similarities.

Comment: thanks, i got it.